Why does fetching an url with axios results in a CORS error?
In my React application using axios, I'm fetching an url. I have an error telling me that my fetch has been blocked by CORS policy and No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. But when i click on my url in my console, i'm able to access the url. Why am i not able to access the url from my react app using axios while i can from my navigator ? I suspect i'm missing a proxy to be able to access this url. Is that the answer ?
Below is the source code for my fetch.
const url = `https://www.waze.com/row-partnerhub-api/waze-map/streetsInfo?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&token=${process.env.REACT_APP_WAZE_GEOCODER}`;
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'cross-origin-opener-policy' : 'same-origin-allow-popups',
        'content-type':'application/json',
      }
    };
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url,config);


You should probably consider whether or not it's safe to have your auth key available to the public before you go with a proxy solution, unless you handle the connection and auth keys in the proxy's code, not on the client. In that scenario though you will need authentication on the proxy to prevent 3rd parties from abusing it.

Ok thank you Kevin ! i dont want my key to be available and adding authentication to the proxy seems complicated, i'll look for others soluces for now.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header, setting it on the request doesn't do anything.
But yes – that resource doesn't allow cross-origin access, so you can't access it using a browser from another origin. A proxy would get around that, but that means you'd have to set up and maintain that proxy. (For development, tooling such as Vite can do that for you, but that won't do for production use.)

But when i click on my url in my console, i'm able to access the url.

Presumably it opens in a new tab and all that? Then you're making a regular request to it, not from another origin.

Yes it opens in a new tab, so i agree with you its not from another origin, i don't understand why Cors error is triggered.

Because that's how CORS works. In order for a script on origin A to request something from an URL in another origin B, that page on origin B must opt into A being allowed to do that, for security. These rules don't apply for navigation, because they're not programmatic requests scripts could read.
